# Kali Linux の端末の文字色や背景色を変更したい

Tags: linux

先日Kali-LinuxをVBoxに入れ直したら色々と変わっていてTerminalのカスタマイズで詰まっています。

```
kali@kali:~$ ls -a
```

の `ls -a` をマトリックスのような緑色にしたいのですがどうしたら良いでしょうか。

TerminalのFile->Preferencesにカラーを弄れそうなところがないし、Settings->Xfce Terminal->Colorsを変更してみても変わらないしで困っています。

どうかお助けください!!

Comment: 手元の環境は Ubuntu Linux 19.10 で xfce4-terminal 0.8.8 ですが、Edit -> Preferences -> Colors で Text color を適当に選ぶとターミナルの文字色がそれっぽい色に変更されます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

解決するヒントになりました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File->Preferences->AppearanceのColorsSchemeでできました。色を選択ではなく決められたStyleに沿っての設定となります。

BlackOnWhite
BlackOnLightYellow
Linux
GreenOnBlack

などです。
僕のマトリックスのような設定は、GreenOnBlackでした。

にしても、Xfce Terminalは一体なんの設定なのでしょうか。。。